# Prototype for python?

Tags: python, prototypejs

I just learned Prototype for Javascript.  It's super convenient: using the $ shortcut, accessing xml elements is not painful any more!

The question: is there a Prototype-like extension for Python?

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you are after when you say $ expanding but there's an xml library for python: http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html.

Comment: I don't wanna start any flame-war type scenario, but JQuery is a similar library that has a much larger user-base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) which has the `xpath` method wherein you could use xpath expressions to select elements. As I understand it, $ in prototype searches and returns an element that has a particular id, in which case could be translated in xpath to `*[@id=<someid>]` like so:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> tree = lxml.etree.XML("<root><a id='1'/><b id='2'/></root>")
>>> tree.xpath("*[@id=1]")
[<Element a at c3bc30>]
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(tree.xpath("*[@id=1]")[0])
'<a id="1"/>'
```

I think the Python standard library includes support for a subset of xpath in ElementTree too so you might be able to implement that there somehow if you do not wish to install lxml (which isn't included in stdlib)...